# Is there a way to REGEX this information.

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to retrieve the date from the line below using a single regEX. The date and time in the string below can change.

```
My Birthday is: Thu Jan 12 23:59:59 GMT 2012.
```

If I use this regEX

```
(?<=My Birthday is: ).+?(?=\.)
```

It will give me this.

```
Thu Jan 12 23:59:59 GMT 2012
```

But I'm looking for this..

```
Thu Jan 12 2012
```

How would I accomplish that with a single Regex Statement that works with .NET

Comment: If you have control over the _generation_ of this text, consider using a date formatter with the desired format.  If you must work on the string as given, you can regex out the two parts and put them together, or take the string you already extracted and drop the time part from the middle.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I applied this date formatter to it, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss GMT yyyy" as you suggested and it worked great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular expression you're after looks like this:

```
^My Birthday is: (\w{3} \w{3} \d\d) \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \w{3}( \d{4})\.$
```

You'll then simply need to join the two captured groups by referencing their respective indexes. I don't know .NET, but it'd look like this in JavaScript:

```
text.replace(/(\w{3} \w{3} \d\d) \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \w{3}( \d{4})\.$/, '$1$2')
```

The one thing you may need to change in the regular expression is the first `\d\d`, depending on how 1–9 are displayed. If they're displayed as 1–9 (rather than 01–09) you'll need to use `\d\d?` instead.